# Delete the extra space from echo command with a pipe

Tags: batch-file

i have a simple problem that i can't manage to solve...

i use this line of batch to print the result of a command in a file without the carriage return :

```
echo | set /P=%tmp% > %~n1.txt
```

but it keeps adding an extra space at the end that i don't want...

i've read some other posts but it is my first batch program so i'm a little lost with there solutions :p

i've tried :

```
%^^^cmd | set /P=%tmp% > %~n1.txt
```

Any ideas  ?

Thanks !

Comment: `set /P=%tmp%<nul>%~n1.txt`

Comment: Thanks dude, works fine ;D

      `<NUL set /P = %tmp%<nul>%~n1.txt`

Comment: ... or slightly clearer, delimiting the value with quotes: `<NUL set /P "=%tmp%"  >%~n1.txt`

Comment: @Squashman - that form without the quotes will fail if the value of `%tmp%` is something like `1`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces from the command itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need some quotes.

```
echo | set /P "=%tmp%" > %~n1.txt
```

Although there is a more efficient way to do it without the pipe. Note that quotes still should be used.

```
set /p "=%tmp%" >"%~n1.txt" <nul
```

If you don't include the quotes, then you would need the following:

```
set /p =%tmp%>%~n1.txt <nul
```

But the unquoted form would fail if the value of `%tmp%` was a digit, or if it ends with space followed by a digit. It would fail because the digit would be treated as a file handle to be used by the redirection. For example, 1 equates to stdout.

The quotes are the simplest manner to cleanly avoid the file handle issue.